# jsf basic question about request scope

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I think this is a jsf basic question but I simply require a little bit of explanation..

I have a login page where I have a link to a CreateAccount page:

```
<div
id="TGOV_popAccount"
style="float: left; margin-left: 60px !important;"><a
href="/createAccount.jsp">Create Account</a></div>
```

Now, this jsp page open a jsf facelet one (yeah, ugly design):

createAccount.jsp:

```
<jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/jsf/account/createAccount.jsf" />
```

so now, this createAccount.jsf has a CreateAccountBean as the backing bean with `request` scope. The **first time** I go to create account page the constructor calles the init method (for some reason the @PostConstruct is not automatically called, that's why I call it from constructor...maybe because of that jsp forward?)

```
public CreateAccountBean() {
    init();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    userLoginVo = new UserLoginVo();
    logger.info("init called");
}
```

If a open again my login page and go again to createAccount page, the init is no longer called and I do not understand why... Having a request scope, it should be reinitialized in this situation, right?

Can you explain me why it fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your JSF out of `/WEB-INF` and link to it immediately.

As to the initialization failure, likely the page is been served from the browser cache instead of from the server. Create a `Filter` which is mapped on `<servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>` and does the following job in the `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```